# How do I switch form Object mode to Edit mode, Weight Paint, Vertex Paint or Sculpt Mode mode in version 2.8?

Tags: experimental-features

Pressing the <kbd>↹ Tab</kbd> key does not toggle object and edit mode in 2.8

How can I access and exit edit mode?

How do I access Weight Paint, Vertex paint or Sculpt Mode mode in version 2.8?

Comment: Blender 2.8 is likely to change a lot before being released.

Answer (score 2):

To toggle between different modes use the keyboard number keys

<kbd>1</kbd> for Object Mode

<kbd>2</kbd> for Edit Mode

[image]

<kbd>3</kbd> for Weight Paint

<kbd>4</kbd> for Vertex Paint

<kbd>5</kbd> for Texture Paint

<kbd>6</kbd> for Sculpt Mode

[image]

Source: https://youtu.be/t-EKbCJagqI?t=356

Comment: Is this confirmed for a fact as the standard way it will be going forward?

Comment: Also see https://blender.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/2349/are-questions-about-the-2-8-branch-on-topic/. For one, even tho minor, I believe they've changed the scale, rotate and translate icons about 3 times now. Good to be preemptive but also try to link to the relevant developer discussion or blog cementing an answer as fact.

Comment: Just built latest 2.8, seems tab behaviour is back. Useful to keep track of ongoing keymap changes https://developer.blender.org/T55194